# how to remove an object in viewpager2 in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm making a viewpage2 view after the code is run in the display object appears as in the picture, how to delete objects circled in red, it appears when the slide / page runs out

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuBKv.png)

**This is Mainactivity class code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager2 viewPager2;
List<user> userList;
userAdaptor userAdaptor;
DatabaseReference mydb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);

    userList = new ArrayList<>();

    userList.add(new user(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "tf","C"));
    userList.add(new user(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,"wuiad","%"));

    userAdaptor = new userAdaptor(this, userList);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(userAdaptor);
  }
```

}

**This is user class code**

```
public class user {
private int item;
private String name;
private String ind;


public user(){

}
public user(int item,String name, String ind){

    this.item =item;
    this.name = name;
    this.ind = ind;
}

public int getItem(){
    return item;
}

public void setItem(int item){
    this.item = item;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getInd(){
    return ind;
}

public void setInd(String ind){
    this.ind = ind;
}
```

}

**This is useradapter class code**

```
  public class userAdaptor extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<userAdaptor.UserViewHolder> {

Context mcontext;
List<user> userList;

public userAdaptor(Context mcontext, List<user>userList){
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.userList = userList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.item, 
parent, false);
    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position) 
{

    user user = userList.get(position);
    holder.tv_name.setText(user.getName());
    holder.tv_ind.setText(user.getInd());
    holder.item.setImageResource(user.getItem());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView item;
    TextView tv_name, tv_ind;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gambar);
        tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textValue);
        tv_ind =itemView.findViewById(R.id.indikator);
    }
   }
 }
```

**This is activity_main.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**this is item.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gambar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textValue"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/indikator"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am amusing you are talking about following scenario*

When there are no pages to scroll, you get the view as you circle in the image. If so then following changes will take care of it ,

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    .............
    android:overScrollMode="never"/>
```

As `viewPager2` is a `RecycleView` kind, then it has the properties of `RecycleView`. What you are getting is a overScroll property of `RecycleView` which work as indication that there are no more item. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381621/how-to-disable-overscroll-effect-on-recyclerview-only-when-you-cant-scroll-anyw) to know more about **overScrollMode**.

Comment: @Dhims glad you find it helpful, please mark it as useful :)

Comment: sorry "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Dhims well.. !! until then best of luck, you will get to 15k someday. :)