# Why is my RecyclerView (CardView) content overlap the button while over-scrolling the list in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, overlap

**I have a RecyclerView in which list of CardView is added and there is an ImageButton when I over-scroll the list the content of list is overlap on button. CardView should be scroll before the ImageButton.**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/id1"
    style="@style/Style1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        style="@style/NoStyle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.002"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.05" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        style="@style/NoStyle"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
        app:noOfColumnInFirstPage="3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Currently, it is like this. I don't want it to overlap with my button, while maintaining my bounce effect.**
[image]

Comment: Is this verbatim because the @ next to parent is wrong `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@parent"`

Comment: It is just a typo sorry `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" `

Comment: Does the image button need to be on top of the CardView or on the bottom of it?

Comment: Actually, both are horizontal. So, there is an image button first and then there is CardView.

Comment: Android doesn't care what you want and this is the whole wrong XML. Using **bold** formatting is pretty useless, when you first speak of a `RecyclerView` and then post a `CardView`. What's the point?

Comment: Sorry @MartinZeitler, I should be more specific about the issue. I have a RecyclerView to display a list of CardViews.

Answer (score 0):

The image button is constrained to the end of the parent, not the start of the CardView.

This `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

Should be this `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/recycler_view"`

Comment: It didn't work. I'm using bounce effect to my RecyclerView so, when I tries to over-scroll it overlaps with the button.

Comment: By over scroll are you dragging if over the image button and its overlapping or are you swiping it and it momentarily goes over the Image button, or both can happen.

Comment: It only overlaps when I try to drag list over the limit (when list reaches end). When I swipe threw pages it doesn't overlap.

Comment: From what I can tell you are using the default LinearLayoutManager you may need to override is default behavior because you are adding the bounce effect. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381621/how-to-disable-overscroll-effect-on-recyclerview-only-when-you-cant-scroll-anyw

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it will stopped when there are no more content which will remove the bounce effect. It helps in overlapping but I will not get bounce effect.